# How to run python scipt in the background(after user input) even if the terminal is closed

Tags: python-3.x, nohup

I have a `python` script that takes some inputs from the user & then executes the code based on the input. The code takes some time to complete; during this code runtime the user can close the terminal(the code is run from a `Linux` machine)
As soon as the user closes the terminal the script stops as well. I know there are options like nohup but it wouldn't accept any input(where input is required in my script).

How can I fix this?

Requirement is -

1. Run the script, enter the inputs
2. Let the code run in the background even if the terminal is closed
3. Also is there a way to write whatever is being printed in the terminal(during the script runtime) to some file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux's screen tmux served my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around possible,
you can split your programm into two parts. 
And start your background task with:

```
import os
usr_inp=input("test input: ")

os.popen(f"python3 background_task.py {usr_inp} &")
```

This should start the other programm in the background, there you can use the input over the sys.argv[1] variable.
(Usually it's not recommended using os.popen)

Comment: thanks for your response, Linux gnu screen served my purpose.